# Trying to get property of non-object Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii2

I am developing on Yii2 and have some problems. 
Here is code:

```
$conditionSymptom = ConditionSymptom::find()->where([
        'condition_id' => $this->id,
        'symptom_id' => $symptomId,
        'age_group_id' => $ageGroupId,
        'gender_id' => $genderId,
    ])->one();
echo $conditionSymptom->condition_id;  // error 'Trying to get property of non-object' is here
```

`var_dump($conditionSymptom);` shows:

```
string(5) "
"
object(common\models\SC\ConditionSymptom)#196 (8) {
  ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(176)
    ["condition_id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["symptom_id"]=>
    int(35)
    ["age_group_id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["possibility"]=>
    int(11)
    ["gender_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sort_value"]=>
    int(1011)
  }
  ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(176)
    ["condition_id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["symptom_id"]=>
    int(35)
    ["age_group_id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["possibility"]=>
    int(11)
    ["gender_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sort_value"]=>
    int(1011)
  }
  ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
string(6) "
"
```

`var_dump` shows that `$conditionSymptom` is object, I don't understand why error is occur.

Please, help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Be sure you var_dump is really related to the $conditionSymptom in the actual situation.  and check if is really set the result for $conditionSymptom..

Comment: the result of your `var_dump` shows `$conditionSymptom` is a string. Try to find out why it is a string, not an object.

Comment: var_dump shows object - object(common\models\SC\ConditionSymptom)

Comment: This simply means that there is no record. `$conditionSymptom` is actually empty. Try checking if `$conditionSymptom` is not empty before retrieving its attributes value.